# Display blog entries from subsite on a page

Tags: sharepoint

I have a blog that was created on a sub-site and I need to show the recent posts of this blog on the main page of the parent site. I have been looking at different web parts in my system and none seem to do that. I also have done quite a bit of googling and I have not found anything similar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches:

1) Use Content Search WP ([link](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/When-to-use-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-or-the-Content-Search-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-346a0f48-38de-409b-8a58-3bdca1768929))

2) Create on sub-site Web Part page. Add "Posts WP" on it. Add content editor WP with iframe on parent site. In IFrame url use "$IsDlg=0" for hidding master page elements.

3) Use JS/Jquery/JSOM etc. Create query to blog and render data as you want.